# Subviews not shown in hierarchy even if parent view is accessibly disabled

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a Nib file with the following hierarchy:

- parent view
- -image
- -label
- -label
- Long press gesture recognizer

I have disabled parent view's Accessibility and enabled the accessibility on its subviews, but still in the Element Tree I am able to see only the parent view. The parent view's class is UIView and I am not using any custom views.

Any ideas what may cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Parent Views "User Interaction Enabled" will have to be set to YES for the accessibility of the subviews to work.

e.g: UITableViewCell